# jQuery descendants selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I want to select all the list items of my UL.

The UL is in a variable called ListBox (ListBox = $('#MyList'))

I used ListBox.children('li') but not all the list items are direct children of the list. Some of them are in a div within the list.

I can try $('#MyList li') but I want to use the ListBox variable

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ListBox.find('li');`

> The [**.find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

`li` is the only element that can be validly contained within a `ul`. If your markup is like this then it is [**invalid**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) and should be changed:

```html
<ul id="MyList">
    <div>
        <li></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

If, however, your markup is more like this:

```html
<ul id="MyList">
    <li>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can simply use [jQuery's `find()` method](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```js
var ListBox = $('#MyList');
ListBox.find('li');
```

Note that `find()` will work on the first example, but you'll want to fix your HTML to make it valid and accessible on all devices. For this reason you may end up only requiring `children()` anyway.